# Silverlight 3 and animated gif

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0

I have a question.

Is there a way that I can show an animated gif in silverlight 3?
I would like a small loading gif to tell the user the application is acutally doing something ...

thx :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of using an animated GIF to tell the user your application is working, why not make a silverlight animation using symbols and a timeline?

Here's a multi-part tutorial on how to create a spinning wait "symbol" in Silverlight:

[Spinning Wait Symbol in Silverlight: Part 1](http://nimblecoder.com/blog/archive/2008/10/08/spinning-wait-symbol-in-silverlight.aspx)

Comment: Animated GIFs are not supported in Silverlight. Voting up since it provides an alternative.